# How to secure a socket server with spring security?

Tags: spring-security, netty

I want to secure a new client server system based on spring with spring-security and (preferably) method-based security annotations.

there are many spring examples for web-apps but so far i didn't find one for non-web java apps.

Basicly i want to handle security for a netty socket in a way that is transparent for my management beans. For example: authenticate the user of the connection once in a netty handler and leave the complete authorization to spring-security and the annotations on my management beans.

is something like this possible?

**EDIT**

i found an example that uses spring-security in [junit integration tests](http://affy.blogspot.de/2005/10/acegi-tutorial-example-of-method-based.html)
i guess i could do it like that but i wouldn't be able to use IoC for my facades so i'm not that fond of the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security supports authentication handling at the method level using annotations. You could try the [`@PreAuthorize`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/prepost/PreAuthorize.html) annotation as described in "[Access Control using @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations)" - though I am unsure on how to get the proper security context in place before the method is called.

Comment: the secury context is exactly the point where i'm woried. the best example that contains what i want (at least partly) is http://affy.blogspot.de/2005/10/acegi-tutorial-example-of-method-based.html but i was hoping for something simpler and more transparent.

Comment: In the example you mention, they are manually setting up the context using the `createSecureContext` method they wrote in the test class. How do you handle authentication in you application? Maybe you could hook up your login / handshake in order to set up the security context similar to the example.

Comment: you are right. according to the documentation SecurityContextHolder.getContext() hold (by default) the context for the current thread. since netty spawns a thread per connection, this should work. i will test this solution

Comment: works. authentication of the current thread is a bit messy, since i have to access the authentication provider directly, but i can now usemethod security.

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure you could hack something together to get it to work, in general Spring Security is *heavily* focused on securing *web* servers. In particular, this focus is evident in the filter-chain architecture of the system that stems from having a filter delegate in web.xml.

I don't remember off-hand if there is a dependency within the core filter chain on there being an httpRequest object that gets passed up and down the chain, but if you are going to try to wrap Spring Security around a socket, putting an adapter in place at that point would be a likely place to start.

So, in short, I would think it's *possible*, but it's definitely not going to be easy, and likely wont get you much benefit, since a large portion of the architecture and default security pieces expects to be wrapped around a web request.

Comment: can you recommend an alternative? i really don't want to handle security by hand. and since i want to use spring as an IoC-Framework, spring security looked like a good idea.

Comment: I don't really know of anything better than Spring Security, so your best bet _may_ just be to hack at the authentication sub-system until you can get it plugged in to what you need and then use the authorization system as-written (which should work just fine as long as the user is authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is not related to spring security, but if it is just "securiy" that you are worried about, take a look at apache [shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/). I have seen some documentation which says that it can secure at socket level, Howerver cant find it out now...:(